# Showing topological properties on a set below

Tags: general-topology

$X=\mathbb{R}$ , My topology is $\mu = \{ U\subset \mathbb{R} : \pi\in  \} \cup \{\emptyset\}$
I want to check if the properties : Hausdorff , first-countable axiom , second-countable axiom , separability are fulfilled in $(X,\mu)$ or not.

Comment: Can you fix your MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @emonHR i tried but did not succeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology is the included point topology:

$$\mathcal{T} = \{U \subseteq \Bbb R: \pi \in U\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$$

Every point $x$ of $\Bbb R$ has a local base of size $1$: $\{x, \pi\}$ is a subset of any open neighbourhood of $x$. So we have a first countable space.

$\Bbb R$ is not second countable, as any base $\mathcal{B}$ must contain **all** sets of the form $\{x,\pi\}$, so must be uncountable.

It is not $T_1,T_2$ as can easily be checked, but it is $T_0$.

$\{\pi\}$ is dense and finite, so $X$ is separable.

Comment: {x,π} of size 1?

Comment: @Maths1999_ it’s one set, isn’t it?

Comment: yes it is , i thought you meant the number of elements in it. How cl{π} = X?

Comment: @Maths1999_ any non- empty open set intersects it.